# Difference between calling task group directly vs. calling it via apply_async in celery

Tags: python, celery

In my tasks.py, I have two celery tasks A and B. Task B takes user id as parameter. Task A collects all the user ids and creates a group of Task B with each user id.

```
@app.task
def A():
    user_ids = get_all_user_ids()
    job = group(B.s(uid) for uid in user_ids)
    job()

@app.task
def B(user_id):
    #some heavy processing
```

In this case, I am directly calling the celery task group. Problem with this is that sometimes it gives a SoftTimeLimitExceeded exception in task A. My question is if I call don't directly call the job rather if call it with apply_async, will this resolve the issue? Also, What is the exact difference between calling a task group directly vs. calling it with apply_async?

Answer (score 1):

`job()` statement implies synchronous call to group.

If you write `job.apply_async()` job's task will be published to queue and A immediately finish. 
Although in that case you probably will not face with SoftTimeLimitExceeded exception, such calls of tasks within a task strongly not recommended due to possible worker deadlock. See https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3031